# One to many mapping in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am new to spring and hibernate. I am creating a job portal. One job can be related with multiple qualification at once. On my add job form i have a select box for choosing 
qualification for a particular job. Qualification can be multiple, means one to many relationship exists, so how can i make this relationship work in hibernate.

In database i have three tables : job,qual,jobqual.

jobqual table is used for saving jobs with multiple qualifications.

My Job.hbm.xml is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="com.jobs.admin.data.Job" table="S_JOBS" >
        <id name="jobKid" column="JOB_KID" type="integer" >
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">job_sequence</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="jobStatus" column="JOB_STATUS" type="boolean" />
        <property name="jobTitle" column="JOB_TITLE" type="string" length="500"/>
        <property name="jobDesc" column="JOB_DESC" type="string" length="4000"></property>
        <property name="jobCity" column="JOB_CITY" type="integer"></property>
        <property name="jobExp" column="JOB_EXP" type="integer"></property>
        <property name="jobStartDate" column="JOB_STARTDATE" type="string"></property>
        <property name="jobEndDate" column="JOB_ENDDATE" type="string"></property>
        <many-to-one name="jobCompany" class="com.jobs.admin.data.Company" column="JOB_COMPANY" ></many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="jobCat" class="com.jobs.admin.data.JobCat" column="JOB_CAT"></many-to-one>
        <set name="jobQual" table="S_JOBQUAL" >
            <key column="JOB_KID" />
        <many-to-many class="com.jobs.admin.data.Qual" unique="true" column="QUAL_KID" />
        </set>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am not able to understand that set which i defined in xml file, should i defined any property in Job class for that ? if yes then how my select box selection would map to this set because select box returns String[] on multiple selection .
How can i accomplish all this, in hibernate ? If any tutorial exists for this type of condition then please send me link.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-1.html) demonstrates an example of one-to-many relationship in hibernate. I hope this helps you. Besides the **set** tag you've used in your xml file represents **java.collection.Set**. In **Job** class, you must have taken a **Set of type Qual**. The example given in the link also demonstrates this mechanism.